# $h(C) = \ln(x)$ on a characteristic curve of the PDE, but the question claims it has infinitely many solutions, How?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following PDE:

$$x^2 y z_x - xy^2 z_y = \frac{1}{z}, \quad on\quad x> 0, y > 0,$$
with the initial value problem,
$$z(x,1/x) = \sqrt{2 \ln(x)} \quad x>1,$$
**and show that it has infinitely many solutions.**

I've found the characteristic curves as $y = \frac{C}{x }, $ and $z^2 (x,y) = \ln(x)^{xy} + h(xy),$
and after plugging the initial value problem, I got
$$h(1) = \ln(x),$$
which does not make any sense; h(C) = h(xy) should, in theory, only depend on which characteristic curve that we are, but it clearly is not the case, so normally, I would say this PDE does not have any solution to the given initial value problem, but the question claims that it has infinitely many, in fact, so I'm confused.

**Question:**

Is there any problem in my analysis ? Why does this PDE have even a solution ? What are those infinitely many solutions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^2 y z_x - xy^2 z_y = \frac{1}{z}, \quad on\quad x> 0, y > 0,\qquad z(x,1/x) = \sqrt{2 ln(x)}$$
Fist method : Brut force, solving the equation with condition.

Charpit-Lagrange system of characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{x^2y}=\frac{dy}{-xy^2}=\frac{dz}{1/z}$$
First characteristic equation from $\frac{dx}{x^2y}=\frac{dy}{-xy^2}$ :
$$xy=c_1$$
Second characteristic equation from $\frac{dx}{x^2y}=\frac{dz}{1/z} \quad;\quad \frac{1}{x^2\frac{c_1}{x}}dx=zdz \quad;\quad z^2-\frac{2}{c_1}\ln(x)=c_2$
$$z^2-\frac{2}{xy}\ln(x)=c_2$$
General solution of the PDE in the form of implicit equation :
$$z^2-\frac{2}{xy}\ln(x)=F(xy)$$
$F$ is any function to be determined according to some specified condition.
$$z(x,y)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{xy}\ln(x)+F(xy)}$$
Condition : $z(x,1/x) = \sqrt{2 ln(x)}$

$$2\ln(x)-\frac{2}{x\frac{1}{x}}\ln(x)=F(x\frac{1}{x})=$$
$$F(1)=0$$
They are an infinity of different functions with the property to have $F(1)=0$.

Thus the problem has an infinity of solutions of this form :
$$z(x,y)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{xy}\ln(x)+F(xy)}$$
where $F$ is any function such as $F(1)=0$.

Second method : Inspection of the characteristics equations versus the specified condition.

The condition $z(x,1/x) = \sqrt{2 ln(x)}$ fits one of the characteristic curves $z^2-\frac{2}{x\frac{1}{x}}\ln(x)=c_2=0$

It is well known that they are an infinity of solutions in this case.

Comment: where did that 2 factor come from in the expression $z^2-\frac{2}{xy}\ln(x)=c_2$ ?

Comment: Typo corrected.

Comment: Don't see any correction ?

Comment: Correction of what ? The equation is correct. $$\frac{dx}{c_1x}=zdz$$
$$2\frac{dx}{c_1x}=2zdz$$
$$2zdz-2\frac{dx}{c_1x}=0$$
$$z^2-\frac{2\ln(x)}{c_1}=c_2$$

Comment: Oh, I see; I forgot that 1/2 factor, thanks.